# Avoiding template helpers in play2.0

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a form which has a input text field bound to an attribute:

```
 @helper.inputText(myForm("username"))
```

But I wish to avoid helpers for the input field. I want to bind the input text field directly with  the attribute in the model, something like:

```
<input type="text" value=@myForm("username")>
```

Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@myForm("username")` returns a [Field](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java#L509) object. So you can access its variables. In your case you want to fill the value of a input field. So you call its `value` variable: `<input type="text" value=@myForm("username").value>`. You can access its error(s), contraint(s), format(s) e.g. in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

As described on the [official documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaFormHelpers) :

```
@helper.input(myForm("username")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="date" name="@name" id="@id" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I want to avoid helpers totally.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot name attribute

```
<input type="text" name="username" value='@myForm("username").value' id="youCanAddyourId" class="orClass">
```

Comment: This worked fine. Thank you. But one issue I now face is, when the page loads, the text field is populated automatically as "Form.Field(username)"